# Referencing job index in LSF job array

Tags: bash, jobs, hpc, lsf

I'm trying to pass the index of a job in a job array as a parameter to another bash script.

```
numSims=3 
numTreatments=6 # uses numTreatments top rows of parameters.csv
maxFail=10
j=1
while [ $j -le $numSims ];
do
    bsub -q someQueue -J "mySim[1-$numTreatments]%2" ./another_script.sh $LSB_JOBINDEX $j $maxFail
    let j=j+1
done
```

The ultimate idea here is to submit, for each of 1,...,`numTreatments`,`numSims` jobs (simulations). I'd like two jobs running at a time (`%2`). Outputs have the form XX_indexNumber_simNumber, where indexNumber runs from 1,...,`numTreatments` and simNumber from 1,...,`numSims`.

Ideally, everything submitted as part of this script would have the same job ID. This isn't yet set up correctly, because all jobs with the same `j` are being assigned a distinct job ID. **My immediate problem is that another_script.sh is not recognizing `$LSB_JOBINDEX` as input--it sees `$j` and `$maxFail` as the first and only two passed parameters.** When I put some other variable in place of `$LSB_JOBINDEX`, there's no problem. What am I doing wrong?

---

*Edit* - some things I've tried: `"$LSB_JOBINDEX"`, `${LSB_JOBINDEX}`, `%I`, and `I=$LSB_JOBINDEX; bsub ... $I $j $maxFail`

Comment: I don't see where `$LSB_JOBINDEX` is set. Since it's empty and unquoted, it's as if it's not there at all which is consistent with the behavior you report.

Comment: From what I understand, `LSB_JOBINDEX` is automatically defined for job arrays, e.g., [here](http://rc.fas.harvard.edu/kb/high-performance-computing/lsf-submitting-lots-of-short-jobs-job-arrays/) and [here](http://www.csc.fi/english/pages/murska_guide/batch_jobs/serial_batch_jobs)

Comment: Well, then for some reason it's not. In any case, I recommend putting quotes around it and the other variables.

Comment: Updated the question with a few of the alternatives I've attempted.

Comment: Try `x$LSB_JOBINDEX` and see what the script receives. If that is equal to `x`, then `$LSB_JOBINDEX` was empty (which it probably is, looking at your results).

Comment: You're right, it's empty. I'm severely confused how I'm supposed to get it full.

Comment: I have no experience with `bsub`, but from the links you sent, it looks like `$LSB_JOBINDEX` is communicated via the environment and is accessible from *within the new job*. Did you try accessing `$LSB_JOBINDEX` from inside `another_script.sh`, without passing it as a parameter?

Comment: BOOM! You're right. I had missed this 'subtlety.' If you want to answer formally, I'll pick it. (Syntactically, though, I don't see how my command differs from the one in the first link.)

Comment: OK, thanks, did it. Looking at the two links, the second one is a better read to me. The first one is confusing and even has a typo in the name of the variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [this link](http://www.csc.fi/english/pages/murska_guide/batch_jobs/serial_batch_jobs):

> The definition above will launch not just one batch job, but 100 batch jobs where the subjob specific environment variable $LSB_JOBINDEX gets values form 1 to 100. This variable can then be utilized in the actual job launching commands so that each subtask gets processed.

In your case, this means that the variable `$LSB_JOBINDEX` is available from inside the script `another_script.sh`. You do not need to pass it as a parameter, but just access `$LSB_JOBINDEX` in your script.

Comment: Thanks again. After looking at half a dozen simplistic uses of `$LSB_JOBINDEX`, I didn't give the good descriptions a fair chance. This lesson should percolate up to the designers of the first link...

Comment: It is also possible to expand `$LSB_JOBINDEX` in the command itself, but I didn't manage to do it in the command arguments unfortunately: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55472377/how-to-use-lsb-jobindex-in-bsub-array-job-arguments-in-platform-lsf