# How to use LSB_JOBINDEX in bsub array job arguments in Platform LSF?

Tags: lsf

I would like to pass `LSB_JOBINDEX` to as an argument to my script instead of using an environment variable.

This makes my script more LSF agnostic and avoids creating a helper script that uses the environment variable.

However, I was not able to use `LSB_JOBINDEX` in arguments: it only works as part of the initial command string.

For example, from a bash shell, I use the test command:

```
bsub -J 'myjobname[1-4]' -o bsub%I.log \
  'echo $LSB_JOBINDEX' \
  '$LSB_JOBINDEX' \
  \$LSB_JOBINDEX \
  '$LSB_JOBINDEX' \
  "\$LSB_JOBINDEX"
```

and the output of say `bsub2.log` is:

```
2 $LSB_JOBINDEX $LSB_JOBINDEX $LSB_JOBINDEX $LSB_JOBINDEX
```

So in this case, only the first `$LSB_JOBINDEX` got expanded, but not any of the following ones.

But I would rather not pass the entire command as a single huge string as the `'echo $LSB_JOBINDEX'` in this example. I would prefer to just use separate arguments as in a regular bash command.

I've also tried to play around with `%I` but it only works for `-o` and related `bsub` options, not for the command itself.

Related: [Referencing job index in LSF job array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11212923/referencing-job-index-in-lsf-job-array)

Tested in LSF 10.1.0. Related documentation: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSWRJV_10.1.0/lsf_admin/job_array_cl_args.html

Answer (score 1):

bsub will add single quotes around the arguments if the argument starts with `$`. For example. If the bsub command line is

```
bsub command -a $ARG1 -b $ARG2
```

Then bsub will add quotes to the arguments to the 2nd and 4th parameters.  The command is stored like this

```
command -a '$ARG1' -b '$ARG2'
```

One way to prevent this is to put the commands in a script.  Like this:

```
$ cat cmd
echo $LSB_JOBINDEX
echo "line 2"
echo $LSB_JOBINDEX
```

Then run your job like this:

```
$ bsub -I < cmd
Job <2669> is submitted to default queue <normal>.
<<Waiting for dispatch ...>>
<<Starting on hostA>>
0
line 2
0
```

Note that the `-I` is not needed. Its just so you can see the job output on the bsub's stdout.

EDIT

OK. Looks like this works. But its not really a serious answer since it's so ugly.  The thing is that bsub will surround the argument with single quotes if the argument starts with `$`.  So the strategy is to find some way to make sure that the first character in the argument isn't a `$`.  One way is to put any character other than `$` as the first character of the argument. Follow it by a backspace literal, followed by the `$`. Note that it needs to be the actual backspace character, not `^` followed by `H`.  Use `ctrl-v` followed by a `ctrl-h` to get the literal appended to the command line.

```
$ bsub -I echo "x^H\$LSB_JOBINDEX" "x^H\$LSB_JOBINDEX"
Job <2686> is submitted to default queue <normal>.
<<Waiting for dispatch ...>>
<<Starting on hostA>>
0 0
```

EDIT2

A tab literal also works.  Not that its much better.

```
$ bsub -I echo "       \$LSB_JOBINDEX" "       \$LSB_JOBINDEX"
Job <2687> is submitted to default queue <normal>.
<<Waiting for dispatch ...>>
<<Starting on hostA>>
0 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Michael. I would like to avoid a helper script as mentioned in the question. The control character hacks are amusing :-) but I think I'll stick to the helper script for now ;-)